# Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxxABC'

Tags: mysql, events, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I want to create following schedule in Mysql. it showing error:  "**Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'xxxxxABC'**"

```
CREATE EVENT resetAccount
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO 
 UPDATE user_master SET AccountNonLocked = 1 WHERE AccountNonLocked = 0  
       and username in 
                    (select username from  user_attempts  where last_modified between          DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 23 HOUR)
                    );
```

I checked all possible solutions mention in previous stackoverflow comments.
I checked PRIVILEGES also for user and run following command also.
"**SELECT host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user**;"

It shows following output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9WAk.jpg)

Also i run "SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();"
output: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMFRd.jpg)

Now, Why i am getting this error as user has all the privileges.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What's your webserver? WAMP or IIS or something else?

Comment: Use the username 'root' with empty password and see if it works. It should work. Then I'll give you the correct answer. This is basically a permissions problem.

Comment: We used username is root only. but it seems in MySQL workbench in "Users and Previlieges" that passoword is compulsary field. because i deleted passoword from the filed and click on "Apply". but default password is coming automatically in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute this:

```
echo "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('password');" > /var/lib/mysql/rootpwd.sql
service mysql restart
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/rootpwd.sql
```

or try to GRANT the privilege

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. As i am not using cmd for execute query. I am using MySQL workbench 6.0 CE to execute the query. And I already try with reconnect to server in Query option in menu bar.

Comment: I run your query "update mysql........"as it is showing "Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)"..!

Comment: Please check first and second image which i attached with the question in which all previleges are there..! currentUser() and User() are different that might be a case for error? what you think in it?

Comment: Now its working fine for me..! I restart main MYSQL server and change password from blank to again root..!

Comment: For MySQL in Docker it would be `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';`